# Fixture is not visible when fixture is defined in a different file in pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I have 2 files:

conftest.py

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

driver = None

@pytest.fixture
def browserSetAndClose():
    global driver

    EXE_PATH = r'C:\Users\1602746\Softwares\chromedriver.exe'
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = EXE_PATH, options = chromeOptions,
                 desired_capabilities = chromeOptions.to_capabilities())
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get('http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/')

    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

xzbc.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

from browser_factory import conftest

def test_abTest(browserSetAndClose):

    wait = WebDriverWait(conftest.driver, 15)
    wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@href, '/abtest')]"))).click()

    a = wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3"))).text
    assert 'A/B Test' in a
```

The problem is I keep getting an error-

> fixture 'browserSetAndClose' not found

when I run the test case function test_abTest.

I tried everything but all in vain.

Also, here is an image of the project structure to show that the aforementioned files are in different directories:
[image: Snapshot to show the above file locations in the project structure]

Comment: If you want the fixture to be available in different modules, put it in a conftest.py file. [Reference](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixture-functions)

Comment: I now refactored browser.py and renamed it to conftest.py but I still get the same issue- fixture 'browserSetAndClose' not found

Comment: Can you repost the file contents after above modification.

Comment: I have edited my post after making the changes.

Comment: You can just keep the `conftest.py` in Herokuapp_python directory. Then you don't need to import it in `xzbc.py` also and the fixture should be available to it.

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked! But what was wrong with the earlier method of importing the file? I don't understand.